# Freezing/Pinning hierarchy columns(slick-viewport-left) not working with aggregators in angular slickgrid

Tags: slickgrid, angular-slickgrid

I am using custom grouping and aggregators. While trying to freeze the hierarchy columns(slick-viewport-left), the aggregated values are disappearing and only the granular level data is visible in slick-viewport-right. I am using Angular version 11 and angular-slickgrid version 2.30.5.

I want to freeze the hierarchy columns without affecting the aggregated column values. Is there any solution for this. Thank you!

Comment: you are using very old Angular and Angular-Slickgrid which are both unsupported because they are EOL, the Tree Data feature was improved a lot since then. You can maybe try `grid.render()` or `grid.invalidate()` to force a re-render of all rows, though I'm not too sure it will help